# How do I move the caret in a Window.selection() textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, caret, getselection

I can identify my currently focussed textbox with [Window.selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection):

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
```

I can identify the caret position with [Selection.focusOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/focusOffset):

```
var focus = selection.focusOffset;
```

Let's say that `focus` is currently **8**, so the caret is **8** characters in.

How do I move the caret position, so it's e.g. **5** characters in?

Example method:

```
selection.setFocusOffset(5); // this method does not exist, so I need something similar
```

The [Selection.extend()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/extend) and [Selection.modify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/modify) methods are able to move around the caret to some extend, but in my usecase where I manipulate and replace content inside the selection I need a more simple way to just determine how many characters in I want to place the caret. Btw: my textbox is a [wysihtml](https://github.com/Voog/wysihtml) textarea, which means that it's not technically a textarea div.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you are wanting to change the start offset of `focus`, but Selection.extend() is only used to change the end offset. Since Selection.modify() is not on any standards track, there will not be a "simple way".

You will need to use [Selection.getRangeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/getRangeAt) which returns a [range object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range). Use the range objects API to [set the start offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/setStart) of your returned range, then use Selection.addRange() to make the new selection. You may want/need to removeRange() to clear the previous selection. I don't know how the browsers would handle overlapping selections.

Comment: I will try to find some time today to make a test in jsfiddle. This was just my best guess after looking through some of the documentation. I'll be learning along with you!

Comment: David Radick - this todo is still hanging out here in the manifest-o-verse x))